# Difference between expression result and what an expression denotes

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[basic.lval] p5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-5.sentence-1) states:

> The result of a glvalue is the entity denoted by the expression.

I have a few questions regarding this and it's implications:
What is the entity denoted by the expression? 
Would this differ from the result? 
[[expr.type] p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1.sentence-2) states:

> The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference

So for example, given the declaration `foo f;` where `foo` is a class type, would the expression `f;` also be an identifier, and that's what it means by the expression denoting an entity, since the expressions name corresponds to the identifier?

**Pretty much what I'm asking is, what does it mean for an expression to denote an entity, and how does it differ from the result?**

Comment: Per the first quote, since the result of a glvalue *is* the denoted entity there can be, by definition, no difference between them. Edit : The first quote refers specifically to glvalues, but I'm not sure if you're just asking about those kinds of expressions or about expressions in general because the bold section is more generic.

Comment: Simplified, but hopefully not too much: expressions are source code and describe things; entities exist in the running program and are things. Expressions denote entities similarly to how, in the stackoverflow context, both the expressions "Krystian S" and "the person who asked this question" denote you.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that [basic.lval]/5 basically say that the concept of naming/denoting/designating and "result of" are used interchangeably in the standard.

> The result of a glvalue is the entity denoted by the expression.
>   The result of a prvalue is the value that the expression stores into its context; a prvalue that has type cv void has no result.
>   A prvalue whose result is the value V is sometimes said to have or name the value V.

A glvalue or a prvalues are expressions [[basic.lval]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-1). All expressions are evaluated. Even a single name appearing in a expression (not in a declaration), is an expression. *Before evaluation* an expression may denote an entity and after evaluation the expression result in this entity.

For example, to evaluate the expression `a+b`, the virtual machine first evaluate `a`. `a` denotes some object, the result of the evaluation of `a` is this object. The same for b. Then the result of the expression `a` and the result of the expression `b` will be used (after some conversions) as operands in the evaluation of the addition.

Only the result of an expression is used by other expressions. So it seems natural to conflate an expression for its result. When we do that we forget that the result is the consequence of the evaluation of the expression.